# Is there any way to see who is connected to the Streaming API?

Tags: limits, streaming-api

In reviewing the Limits API, I see that we have 2000 Durable Streaming clients available via the DurableStreamingApiConcurrentClients field. I show that there are currently (and almost always) > 700 in use. I only have one named push topic with one client, so obviously that is not where the 700 are from.

1. What else could be using these?
2. Is there any way to see who/what is consuming these connections?

Comment: Do you have any appexchange packages installed that might be using it? I know the developer console uses the streaming API. After opening it in my dev org the usage with from 20 remaining to 19 remaining.

Comment: Maybe.. we have a number of appexchange packages, but I which one(s) might it be? Kinda what I am looking to figure out.

Comment: How many users are in your full sandbox? Might be easier to slowly step through functionality there while monitoring usage.

Comment: I don't think the [`StreamingChannel`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/streamingChannel.htm) will tell you much unless the LastReferencedDate changes when a client subscribes.

Comment: Another long shot, but check the Event Monitoring if you have it enabled. Might be something in the [API Event Log](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_api.htm).

Comment: None of these things seem to tell me who/what is attached to the streaming events. Irritating when Salesforce puts limits in place, but provides no way to see what is consuming the limits.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue.  It seems like I'm hitting a limit even though when I check the limits it says I have plenty of `remaining` connections. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: From what I recall, any user that is using a console app, sucks up at least 1 (maybe more) connection (in order to get the notifications in the app)